# why does index.php shows up in url, when site loads for first time (yii)

Tags: .htaccess, url, yii, url-rewriting

I have used my htaccess file and yii rules to hide the index.php from my url, it all works fine apart from the 1st time when the site loads, index.php can be seen in the url. Can anyone shed any light on why this may be happening? Have a look at www.whitecollarboxinglondon.com

Thanks.

Karen.

Comment: i dint see any index.php. cleear your browser history and try

Comment: thanks for your reply, i still see it on my local version though

Comment: The most likely reason for you seeing it is that you at some point had a 301 redirect. Clear your browser cache and it will restore it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration in your URL Manager:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    ..............................
    ..............................
 )
```